# Covering the sphere with connected closed sets

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

I am given the following question .

Can $S^{2}$ be covered by finite number of connected closed sets $A_{1},...,A_{n}$ such that

1. Each has diameter less than a given $\epsilon$ .
2. $\cup A_{n}= S^{2}$
3. $\displaystyle A_{k}\cap\bigg(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}A_{i}\bigg)$ is connected for all $k\leq n$ ?

My attempt:-

My first thought was to view it as a standard classic football and prove it for pentagons and hexagons. But then I realized that it is not very simple as ordering the sets such that property $3$ becomes a problem and moreover the pentagons and hexagons have a curvature in this case.

So I thought of covering with small enough "curved" squares . But I am struggling to make the argument fully rigorous.

I view the height of the sphere which is $1$ as the interval $[0,1]$ and divide into $\frac{1}{n^{2}}=\frac{1}{m}$  many may pieces where $\epsilon>\frac{1}{n}$.

Now the surface area of the sphere between $0\leq h\leq \frac{1}{m}$ is just $\frac{2\pi}{m}$ . And so I divide this surface area into $m$ many "curved squares" of area $\frac{2\pi}{m^{2}}$ and stack them so as the property $3$ holds.

Now it is hard to find the exact diameter $=\sup\{d(x,y):\,x,y\in A_{i}\}$    . But as the area of the square is taken to be small enough , we can say that it is less than $\epsilon$. If not then we can again scale it to make it so.

Now we proceed inductively and cover the sphere up with such squares for each interval of heights $[\frac{k}{m},\frac{k+1}{m}]$ for $k=1,...,m-1$.

Now this seems intuitively okay but I am worried about the connectedness part as we move up a level in height and I can't seem to make it fully rigorous.

Can someone  explain to me if I am going wrong somewhere or can suggest me a better way of solving this ?

Any help is appreciated.

PS. This was asked in a Algebraic Topology course as a similar argument was used to lift a path $\alpha :[0,1]\to X$ given a space $Y$ and a covering map $p$ .

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle A_{k}\cap\bigg(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}A_{i}\bigg)$ is connected _for all_ $k\le n$? Because otherwise you can just take $A_n$ to be the empty set.

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant . I'll edit it

Comment: Quantifiers are missing in this question: Do you mean that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $n$ and a collection of subsets as in the question?

Comment: @MoisheKohan As in the case of Homotopy lifting from the square to a space Y where we used Lebesgue Number Theorem, this excercise was given to see if similar conditions hold for another compact set like the sphere. So for the epsilon we get for a particular open cover due to Lebesgue number theorem, we want to cover our compact space by some number of finite sets which have diameter less than epsilon and the property $3$ holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at a globe:

[image]

Meridians and latitude circles divide $S^2$ into closed triangular surface pieces (around north and south pole) and closed quadrangular surface pieces. Taking sufficiently many meridians and latitude circles ensures that all these pieces have diameter less than the given $ϵ$. Number the pieces as follows:

1. Number the latitude circles from north to south by $L_1,\ldots, L_m$ and the meridians counterclockwise by $M_1,\ldots,M_n$. Set formally $M_{jn+i} = M_i$ for all $j \in \mathbb N$ and $i = 1,\ldots, n$.
2. For $i=1,\ldots, n$ let $A_i$ be the triangular surface piece bounded by $M_i, M_{i+1}$ and $L_1$.
3. For $j = 1,\ldots, m-1$ and $i = jn+1,\ldots,jn +n$ let $A_i$  be the quadrangular surface piece bounded by $M_{i}, M_{i+1}$ and $L_j, L_{j+1}$.
4. For $i = mn+1,\ldots,mn +n$ let $A_i$ be the triangular surface piece bounded by $M_{i}, M_{i+1}$ and $L_m$.

This gives us $N = (m+1)n$ surface pieces. It is clear that $\displaystyle A_{k}\cap\bigg(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}A_{i}\bigg)$ is connected for all $k\leq N$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the approach which I was thinking of by "curved squares" . Specifically I had the image of  a "disco ball" in my mind. Can you please also clarify if my method was correct or wrong?

Comment: @Dovahkiin Your approach is correct. As you say, it is what I made explicit in my answer (especially concerning the numbering of the pieces).

Comment: please don't mind an additional query....I was thinking about exactly the same question but applied to the circle $S^{1}$ . There it should be false right?. That is we cannot find such closed sets which cover $S^{1}$ with those properties?

Comment: @Dovahkiin I guess it is impossible, but a formal proof will not be easy. I suggest you officially ask another question.

Comment: Thanks . I'll do so